# How to pass props with navigation in react native using typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have a login page, after logging in I am able to navigate to my home page. But I also want to pass props when navigating to home page.

Login Page:

```
const [daysLeft, setDaysLeft] = useState(14);

const getHome = () => {
  props.navigation.replace(NavigateTo.Main, {screen: NavigateTo.Home, daysLeft: daysLeft});
};
```

After this I am running my login api, and checking if phone is verified or not:

```
if (!user.is_phone_verified) {
  getEmailVerification();
} else {
  getHome();
}
```

Here my phone is verified and my `getHome()` is executed, taking me to my home page.

Home Page:

```
const HomeScreen = (props: any) => {

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("days: ",props.daysLeft);
  }, []); 

// Remaining code
```

But I am getting `days:  undefined` in my console. I am new to using react native and I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: What is the navigation library that you're using (you tagged both react-navigation and react-native-navigation and what is the `NavigateTo.Main` function?